# Notice: No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\Net\SSH2.php on line 1561

Tags: php, ssh

i have problems with connect to my ssh trough php (ssh is on ubuntu 16.04 server)
php code

```
<?php
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib1.0.2'); 
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('****:22');
if (!$ssh->login('***', '***')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

and error is

```
Notice: No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\Net\SSH2.php on line 1561
Login Failed
```

Comment: I hope that's not your actual userid and password you've just posted...

Comment: that's only examples. I'm not dumb to show my IP, Name, pass